# Can I initialize static float Variable during runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I need to set the value of static float variable during run time but I am unable to do that.
I will provide example to elaborate my situation

afile.h

```
class B {
    static float variable1;
    static float variable2;
 public:
    afunction(float a, float b);
}
```

afile.cpp

```
#include 'afile.h'
B::afunction (float a, float b) {
    float B:variable1 = a;
    float B:variable2 = b;
}
```

As you see in the code above the function 'afunction' is called and then the variables 'variable1' and 'variable2' has to be set. I know the code in definition of 'afunction' is wrong however I need a way to set value of variable1 and variable2 during run time.

If it is relevant to my code, I am using Visual Studio 6.0 to develop the application

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: yes I tried the way I have shown in my example, it does not work. Gives an error 'definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope'

Comment: **1** What does the C++ textbook of your choice tell you how you assign values to a variable? **2** Why do you use a compiler that has been outdated for at least 10 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write:

```
B::afunction (float a, float b) {
    B::variable1 = a;
    B::variable2 = b;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg THX for the note, I just copied the code and didn't spot that

Comment: @user2060711: It's great you gave us the error code, however the message would help too...

Comment: @user2060711 I've edited the sample according Joachim Pileborgs coment

Comment: Even though this apparently already fixed OP's problem I'd like to point out that the `B::` in `B::variable1` is pretty redundant considering `afunction` is part of the `B` class its already going to look within the class scope.

Comment: Doesn't the static variables variable1 and variable2 have to be defined before using them?

Comment: @sajas I just gave an excerpt of what to change from the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

At first you'll have to set the static variable to something before you can reference it.

Without `int test::m_ran = 0;` you would get `undefined reference to 'test::m_ran'`

```
#include <cstdio>

class test
{
public:
    static void run() { m_ran += 1; }
    static void print() { printf("test::run has been ran %i times\n", m_ran); }

private:
    static int m_ran;

};

int test::m_ran = 0;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        test::run();
        test::print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
test::run has been ran 1 times
test::run has been ran 2 times
test::run has been ran 3 times
test::run has been ran 4 times
```